# How do I connect an Antenna Cable to a Sat Nav's Power Cable?

Tags: electrical, audio, wiring, kia

I have just purchased a new Sat Nav Unit and would like to connect my original Radio Antenna to the Sat Nav Unit, so that I am able to pick up Radio Stations and control their output via the Sat Nav Unit.

**Radio Antenna Cabling**

This is how the Radio Cabling currently looks:

[image]

As per the image, we can see there is a Black Wire that is then connected to a Blue Wire and then there is a Red Wire that is connected to another Red Wire with a Fuse inbetween.

**Power Cable**

How do I then connect the above Wires to the below Power Cable that came with the Sat Nav Unit?

[image]

I assume I would need to use some kind of Splicer to 'tap in' the Radio Antenna wires into the Power Cable wires?

With this in mind, could someone advise on which colour I would need to 'tap' the Red Wire into and which colour the Black/Blue Wire would need to be 'tapped' into.

Power Cable Colours ...

- Black;
- Red;
- Blue;
- White;
- Grey;
- Black and White;
- Dark Grey;
- Dark Purple;
- 2 x Orange;
- Blue & White;
- Purple;
- 2 x Green;
- Yellow;
- Pink & Black (With a 'Key 2' Label attached).

**Previous Power Cable**

I can see that the previous Sat Nav Unit's Power Cable has indentations, from the Splicer, on the Blue and Black Wires.  As such, would it be fair to assume that it is the Red and Black Wires that need to be connected to the Radio Antenna Wires or should I ignore the original setup?

**Earthing/Grounding**

Do I need to concern myself with grounding any of the Wires?  When I took out the original Sat Nav, I could see that a Power Cable's Pink Wire had been cut and stripped and then wrapped around a Screw on the rear of the Sat Nav Unit.  Is this Earthing or something else that I need to be aware of?  Any guidance would also be appreciated on this matter too.

**Suppliers**

I have contacted the Suppliers who have stated that they are unsure and are not able to provide any guidance on wiring.  Furthermore, the Manual does not give any details on wiring configurations; hence trying to figure this out for myself.

Any assistance, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the make and model of the sat nav unit?  As written this sounds pretty crazy, but I have to allow for the possibility that a sat nav may have a way to inject voice instructions into your radio's speakers, and that your radio would have a way to accommodate that.  intercepting antenna seems like the hard way, though.

Comment: The Sat Nav is an After Market product, which can be found at http://www.a-sure.com.hk/products/gps-car-radio/kia/7-wince-dvd-gps-navi-car-radio-for-kia-ceed-sportage-picanto-sorento-rio-carens-carnival-cerato-opt-1058.html The Radio Antenna did not come with the Sat Nav.  It is a separate feature that worked with the previous Sat Nav.  I am looking to attach it to the Sat Nav Unit, via the Power Cable, just like the original setup.  Just not sure which coloures Wires go where and whether I would need to Earth anything.

Comment: The colours of the wires are not so useful - there are some generally accepted combinations (eg red for +ve) but these are not universal by any means. You need to look at the sat nav, radio and your car's manuals to understand what each wire is used for.

Comment: @RoryAlsop:  The Sat Nav and separate Radio Antenna did not come with the Car.  It was purchased separately.  What would I be looking for, within the Car Manual.  The Sat Nav works perfectly fine.  It is just figuring how to connect the Radio Antenna to the Sat Nav Unit.  The Sat Nav Unit's Manual does not provide any details on how to wire a Radio Antenna to the Sat Nav Unit.  I have access to a Multimeter.  Would this help in identifying the relevant Wires to be connected?